# What's the issue in accessing associative array element in smarty in following scenario?

Tags: arrays, smarty, associative-array, smarty2

I've following array title $value which I've assigned to smarty template.

```
 Array
        (
            [id] => 175
            [start_date] => 2014-07-01
            [end_date] => 2014-07-31
            [count] => 3
            [rebate_type_id] => 2
            [created_at] => 1406031299
            [updated_at] => 1406031299
            [applicable_states] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [state_id] => 0
                            [rebate_id] => 175
                            [state_name] => All States
                        )

                )
            [manufacturer_id] => 49
            [company_name] => Blue Nun
            [manufacturer_image_path] => 
        )
```

For accessing the inner array element I wrote following code but it's not working. Can you please correct the mistake I made in below code?

```
{if $value.appplicable_states.0.state_name == 'All States'}
                  All States
                {/if}
```

Comment: If `$value` is an array you will either need to use `$value.THE_INDEX_YOU_NEED.applicable_states...` or a `foreach` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in PHP you made such assignment (I've simplified array):

```
$data= array('applicable_states' => array(0 => array('state_name' => 'All States')));
$smarty->assign('value',$data);
```

in Smarty you can use:

```
{if $value.applicable_states.0.state_name =='All States'}
All States
{else}
Not All States
{/if}
```

Output for this is:

> All States

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I smartied, but I think you need to assign arrays to a variable first to be able to access the elements of the array:

```
{assign var=states value=$value.appplicable_states}
{$states[0].state_name}
```

or more likely:

```
{assign var=states value=$value.appplicable_states}
{foreach from=$states item=state}
    {$state.state_name}
{/foreach}
```